# Javascript "this" in a jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

How can I call functionOne correctly within the Jquery change function?  "this" is no longer referencing the object.

```
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    $('input').change(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         this.functionOne(); // this is no longer calling function one 
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo? You have two `functionTwo`s

Comment: and no comma after first `functionTwo:` either?

Comment: `this.functionOne()` does not exist in the `functionThree` scope; `this` refers to the jQuery object inside there (the event handler) for the input element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have two different values you want to use and jQuery is already putting one of them in `this`, you can just save the other value in a variable in a higher scope:

```
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    // save value if this so it can be used later in this scope
    var self = this;
    $('input').change(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         self.functionOne();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, since this is a statically named `NameSpace.object`, you could also just refer to that name directly:

```
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    $('input').change(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         NameSpace.object.functionOne();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, since jQuery provides a mechanism [`.change( [eventData], handler )`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-eventData-handler) for passing data to an event handler, you can use that too:

```
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    $('input').change(this, function(e){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         e.data.functionOne();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The jQuery mechanism is not my favorite here because I think the code that calls `e.data.functionOne()` is less obvious (the reader has to look back in the code to figure out what `e.data` is), but that's just my personal opinion for this situation.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, is there a benefit or disadvantage to either solution?

Comment: You're missing a comma between your two functionTwos and oh yeah, you have two functionTwos ;)

Comment: @j08691 - typos corrected (those were typos in the OP's question that we all just copied, but have now been fixed in the question too).  Anyway, they're fixed here now.

Comment: I know. I saw them when the question was posted. Funny how the first two answers both ignored those mistakes.

Comment: @jfriend00 `NameSpace.object.functionThree` would still have to be called for change event to be registered at input element ?

Comment: @guest271314 - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Without actually being called `NameSpace.object.functionThree()` , `change` event at `input` element within `NameSpace.object.functionThree` function  would not be registered , or call `NameSpace.object.functionOne` ?

Comment: @MicFin - If you're normally calling `NameSpace.object.functionOne()` anyway from outside this structure, then I'd just stick with that scheme here too.  Otherwise, it's really your choice.

Comment: @guest271314 - yes, it is assumed that someone calls `functionThree()` to start things off.  This is obviously a made-up example for purposes of the question.  I think the OP knows they need to call that.

Comment: yes, thank you for understanding my assumptions and typos @jfriend00!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to keep a reference to it using, conventionally called`self`

```
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    var self = this;
    $('input').change(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         self.functionOne(); // this is no longer calling function one 
       }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Under normal circumstances you could `bind` your callback to your object using `this`.  But in this case I have no idea how it interacts with jquery's overriding of `this` to reference the element that triggered the callback...

Comment: You're missing a comma between your two functionTwos and oh yeah, you have two functionTwos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting variable of `NameSpace` within `functionThree` , calling `NameSpace.object.functionThree()` to set `change` event at `input` element

```js
var NameSpace = {};
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
     alert("functionOne")
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    var ns = this;
    $('input').change(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
        ns.functionOne(); // this is no longer calling function one 
       }
    })
  }
}

NameSpace.object.functionThree()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the optional [`eventData`](http://api.jquery.com/change/#change-eventData-handler) parameter of `jQuery.change([eventData ],...)`.

By passing `this` to `eventData` your can access it from inside the handler through the event variable.

```
$('input').change(this,function(e){
    ...
    e.data.functionOne(); 
    ...
}
```

---

```js
var NameSpace = {};
NameSpace.object = {
  functionOne: function(){
     // stuff
     alert("functionOne")
  },
  functionTwo: function(){
     this.functionOne();  // this works correctly
  },
  functionThree: function(){
    $('input').change(this,function(e){
       if ( $(this).val() > 1) {
         e.data.functionOne();  
       }
    })
  }
}

NameSpace.object.functionThree()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: nice solution, clever!